# How to setup grid/clutster computers?

Tags: computer-building, parallel-processing

We have 3 labs and each lab have 30 computers having different OS's on them windows, Ubuntu mostly, so i was thinking if i can connect them using grid computing, so we can use them for our research and other stuff by using MPI and parallel computing. I am interested if that is possible ?

Comment: Just a tiny tad vague. What OS are these running?

Comment: @Ecnerwal few running windows 8 and others running windows 7

Comment: @Ecnerwal do you have any idea ?